# How can I go through the child forms according to their current order?

Tags: c#

Good morning,
I'm doing a project mdi in c #,
from my perent form call a child from :

(form1 parent)

```
private void formularioToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frmPrueba = new Form2();
    frmPrueba.MdiParent = this;
    frmPrueba.Text = "Form " + Convert.ToString(x = x + 1);
    frmPrueba.Show();
}
```

my problem is, that when I create several instances of the child form and then change position between the forms, I always see the same order of the children forms when I perform the following action:

(form2 child)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= MdiParent.MdiChildren.Count() - 1; x++) {
        MessageBox.Show(MdiParent.MdiChildren[x].Text);
    }
}
```

How can I go through the child forms according to their current order?
Sorry my english, thanks for all

Comment: On a side note, you can probably use a foreach instead of a for over that child collection. In order to sort them you can use the linq sort operator, are you just looking to sort them by which window is on top or their position on screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check the "Z-position" of form in a MDI application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708505/how-to-check-the-z-position-of-form-in-a-mdi-application)

Answer (score 0):

Add a property `Index` to `Form2`

```
public int Index {get; set;}
```

Then when changing positions of the children, set the index property to it's new location.

finally

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var children = MdiParent.MdiChildren.OrderBy(c => c.Index).ToList();
    for (int x = 0; x < children.Count; x++) {
        MessageBox.Show(children[x].Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not forego the index and just use an existing property of the child forms to sort instead? What's the criteria for setting the index property? If it is the form's position on screen it seems like you are adding additional properties to the form that already exist.

Comment: @Charleh I'm not really a Windows developer, but came across this because it was only tagged c#. If MdiForms already have an existing property that identifies position, definitely he should use that. If you know what it is, please add an answer.

Comment: thanks for response the question, but I have not been able to solve it, as in delphi the route of the forms is made according to the visual order, the order z changes, but in c # this order z seems not to vary when I activate a different form, always shows me the order as they were created, I hope you get my idea I'm translating from google.

Comment: I'll see if I can put an example together

Answer (score 0):

I want the messages to appear in the following order:
Form 1
Form 3
Form 2
Form 4

instead it looks me

Form 1
Form 2
Form 3
Form 4

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Manuel, better to edit the existing question than to post additional parts as answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708505/how-to-check-the-z-position-of-form-in-a-mdi-application it looks like someone has already answered here.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution works well on my purpose, but I read that EnumChildWindows is better??? thanks anyway!!!

```
   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint uCmd);

    const uint GW_HWNDFIRST = 0;
    const uint GW_HWNDLAST = 1;
    const uint GW_HWNDNEXT = 2;
    const uint GW_HWNDPREV = 3;



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form fr;
        var hwndTmp = GetWindow(Handle, GW_HWNDFIRST);

        while (hwndTmp != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            if (Handle == hwndTmp)
            {
                fr = (Form)Form.FromHandle(hwndTmp);
                MessageBox.Show(fr.Text);
            }

            hwndTmp = GetWindow(hwndTmp, GW_HWNDNEXT);
            if (hwndTmp != (IntPtr)0)
            {
                fr = (Form)Form.FromHandle(hwndTmp);
                MessageBox.Show(fr.Text);
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly I couldn't find any way to do this without resorting to invoking `User32.dll`

The extern invoke comes from this post on codeproject:  https://www.codeproject.com/Messages/4486612/Re-Mdi-Child-Window-Z-Order.aspx

Code is thus:

```
    private void ShowWindowOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var children = this.MdiChildren.ToList();

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var child in this.GetChildrenSortedByZOrder())
        {
            sb.AppendLine(child.Text);
        }

        MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
    }

    private delegate bool EnumChildProc(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hWndParent, EnumChildProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

    private IEnumerable<Form> GetChildrenSortedByZOrder()
    {
        List<IntPtr> handles = new List<IntPtr>();
        if (IsHandleCreated)
        {
            EnumChildWindows(Handle,
                (hWnd, lparam) =>
                {
                    handles.Add(hWnd);
                    return true;
                }, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        List<Form> children = new List<Form>(handles.Count);
        foreach (IntPtr handle in handles)
        {
            Form form = FromHandle(handle) as Form;
            if (form != null)
                children.Add(form);
        }
        return children;
    }
```